# G body Windshield wiper module

Tags: chevrolet

I am unable to locate a replacement "Windshield Wiper Module" which is apparently and OEM GM part used on early versions of GM Intermittent Windshield Wipers (IWW).  If I cannot locate a replacement, can anyone comment on how the module functioned so I can try to replace it with a more modern Relay module that can simply operate the wipers without being intermittent.  This is the very first time that I have looked for a part for my old cars that it cannot be found, at any price.  It seems that either the OEM part was bulletproof and mine is an unlucky occurrence, or they were very poorly designed and virtually everyone who owned a mid 80's GM G-Body somehow wired around the module so as to be able to operate a G-Body in the rain?  Does anyone out there happen to have a failed one so I could try to reverse engineer it and actually build a few to see if there is interest in them?

The problem with mine is that if the wipers are switched "on", they will not turn off until the ignition key is switched to off.  Dry windshield or at-speed stopping and then restarting is not a lot of fun.

Comment: In the future, if you post the vehicle make/model/year, we can help you a lot more. With that information, I could probably give you the part number you need and exactly where to purchase said item at. Mid-80's GM G-Body isn't very helpful. I know it's like a Buick Regal or a GN, but give me the year and exact model. Helps a ton.

Comment: @Paulster2 That's funny I assumed that he was talking about a G-Van. Again to your point Make model year should be included.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in one of two places. It's going to be in the switch (turn signal mounted) or in the electronics of the wiper motor. My suggestion is that it will be in the motor itself.

Two places you can look which usually have parts for older cars ... and believe me when I say, "mid-80's" is not old. Check on [rockauto.com](http://www.rockauto.com) and on [GMPartsDirect.com](http://www.gmpartsdirect.com/catalog/frameset.cfm). Both have a LOT of parts.